# python lists - convert an existing list of lists into a dict with multiple values per key using a comprehension

Tags: python, loops, nested, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a relatively simple problem that is easily solved with `setdefault`, but I'm self-learning comprehensions right now and can't figure out how to do this with a comprehension.

Let's say I have a nested list where some of the inner lists have the same keys. This means that I should be able to generate a dict where some keys have multiple values.  I keep trying to somehow append the values but every time it just returns that last single digit value or else give an error.

Here is an example:

```
>>> strlist
['hello w', 'hello', 'hello c', 'hello c c', 'dog']

>>> [[k,v] for k in set(sum([x.split() for x in strlist],[])) for v,x in enumerate(strlist) if k in x]
[['hello', 0], ['hello', 1], ['hello', 2], ['hello', 3], ['w', 0], ['c', 2], ['c', 3], ['dog', 4]]
```

I also tried it with a list of tuples, a tuple of tuples, a set of lists, a set of tuples, etc.  Still can't get it to work with a comprehension.

Here are a few failed attempts:

```
>>> dict([(k,v) for k in set(sum([x.split() for x in strlist],[])) for v,x in enumerate(strlist) if k in x])
{'hello': 3, 'w': 0, 'c': 3, 'dog': 4}

>>> {k:k[v] for k,v in [[k,v] for k in set(sum([x.split() for x in strlist],[])) for v,x in enumerate(strlist) if k in x]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#285>", line 1, in <module>
    {k:k[v] for k,v in [[k,v] for k in set(sum([x.split() for x in strlist],[])) for v,x in enumerate(strlist) if k in x]}
  File "<pyshell#285>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
    {k:k[v] for k,v in [[k,v] for k in set(sum([x.split() for x in strlist],[])) for v,x in enumerate(strlist) if k in x]}
IndexError: string index out of range

>>> {k:{v} for k,v in [[k,v] for k in set(sum([x.split() for x in strlist],[])) for v,x in enumerate(strlist) if k in x]}
{'hello': {3}, 'w': {0}, 'c': {3}, 'dog': {4}}
```

The goal is to get this:

```
>>> {'hello': {0, 1, 2, 3], 'w': {0}, 'c': {2, 3}, 'dog': {4}}
```

Is this even possible with a comprehension or must I use one of the more common traditional loop methods?

Comment: What is `strlist`?

Comment: `>>> strlist = ['hello w', 'hello', 'hello c', 'hello c c', 'dog']`

Comment: is it a compulsion to do in one line?

Comment: yes it is, but only driven by curiosity because I'm learning about dict-comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your method to transform `strlist` to list of lists and then you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    ["hello", 0],
    ["hello", 1],
    ["hello", 2],
    ["hello", 3],
    ["w", 0],
    ["c", 2],
    ["c", 3],
    ["dog", 4],
]   

d = defaultdict(set)
for x, y in lst:
    d[x].add(y)
    
print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'hello': {0, 1, 2, 3}, 'w': {0}, 'c': {2, 3}, 'dog': {4}})
```

Since, you ask for a dictionary-comprehension:

```
d = {k: set(y for x, y in lst if x == k) for k, _ in lst}
```

Comment: thanks for the good tip, but i'm really trying to see if this can be done using a dict-comprehension

Comment: @user1026169, Please find the same. Edited.

Comment: thanks very much for explaining this.  here is the completely impractical example but helped me visualize whats happening: ````{k: set(y for x,y in [[k,v] for k in set(sum([x.split() for x in strlist],[])) for v,x in enumerate(strlist) if k in x] if x==k) for k,dummy_ in [[k,v] for k in set(sum([x.split() for x in strlist],[])) for v,x in enumerate(strlist) if k in x]}````

Comment: I just want to inform you that one line codes do not always favour in every cases. What's more important is readability. I would suggest to break down to multiple lines which would probably aid you debugging at a later stage.

Comment: thanks very much for clarifying.  this was just to satisfy my curiosity for the one line comprehension.  these posts helped a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of doing it in one line, using dict comprehension. However, I'm not sure if this is a best option in terms of efficiency than a more conventional for loop, using things like `setdefault()` and some temporal list.

```
list_ = ['hello w', 'hello', 'hello c', 'hello c c', 'dog']
result = {
    word: {i for i, phrase in enumerate(list_) if word in phrase}
    for string in list_
    for word in string.split()
}
```

**content of `result`:**

```
{'hello': {0, 1, 2, 3}, 'w': {0}, 'c': {2, 3}, 'dog': {4}}
```

Comment: thanks, this helps me better understand dict-comprehensions. much appreciated.